# Attempting to learn about decryption

Tags: php, wordpress, encryption, passwords

So I am trying to learn more about encryption/decryption. I have a wordpress blog with passwords on it. I am wondering what type of encryption this is, and the steps to go about decrypting it:

$P$B0GFbv8OYRk.jZxN88dfBO0/iJdLL1.

Comment: You cannot decrypt passwords on any well-designed system; they use a one-way hash function.

Comment: @Wooble indeed! (Clicking "I forgot my password" and have them send me my actual password by email always makes my cry.)

Comment: Wordpress is Open source Software. If you want to understand how they secure passwords, you can go have a look at their code yourself.

Comment: Which PHP page is the encryption/hashing on? I was looking through and couldn't find which page it was on. I have one of the newer versions of Wordpress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am wondering what type of encryption this is, and the steps to go about decrypting it:
>   `$P$B0GFbv8OYRk.jZxN88dfBO0/iJdLL1`

It's not encryption, but hashing. The method used by wordpress is called *phpass*, the implementation can be found in the wordpress code-base for example.

As it's not encrypted, you can not decrypt it. You can try to find a plain-text however that matches the hash. This can be done with bruteforcing. A program that does this for the wordpress hashes is [hashcat](http://hashcat.net/).

Answer (score 0):

i think oneway hashing algorithms such as `sha1` `md5`  which outputs a [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded string as the size of the input text to the method

Example : -  **PlainText (x) -> sha1() -> base64 String (y)**

always **x = y**  becouse these ciphers are called [block ciphers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher)

These `sha1` and `md5` functions are considered as **[one way hash algos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function)**

These functions are considered as

> An algorithm that turns messages or text into a fixed string of
>   digits, usually for security or data management purposes. The "one
>   way" means that it's nearly impossible to derive the original text
>   from the string.